# sending JSON issue - does not seem to send it correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

So I am doing a GET via AJAX to a controller method to return back some JSON.
returning back JSON is fine but sending the parameters to construct a simple object does not - results as the default values for that object!

any ideas?

model:

```
public class CoreViewModel
{
public int Id {get; set;}
public int ExtensionId {get;set;}
public string Zip {get; set;}
public int ShopId {get; set;}
}
```

controller:

```
public ActionResult GetDetails(CoreViewModel model)
        {
            return Json(new DetailsViewModel(model), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: serviceUrl + "GetDetails/",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                crossDomain: false,
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: '{"Zip":"@Model.Zip","ShopId":@Model.ShopId,"ExtensionId":@Model.ExtensionId,"Id":@Model.Id}', 
                success: function(data) {

                    };

                },
```

..
..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed.

remove the ' from the start and end. (single quote)

Answer (score 0):

Try sending data as below

```
  data:JSON.stringify({"Key":"value"}),
```